# What's difference in calculating gradients of these two methods in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
grads_and_vars = []
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    if 'synthetic' in var.name:
        grads_and_vars.append(self.optim.compute_gradients(self.grad_total_loss, var_list=[var])[0])
    else:
        for k in self.grad_output.keys():
            if k in var.name:
                grads = tf.gradients(self.layer_out[k], var, self.grad_output[k])[0]
                grads_and_vars.append((grads,var))
# minimize the gradient loss and only change the dni module
self.train_op = self.optim.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=self.global_step)
```

I am reading into someone's code, could anyone explains to me what's the difference between

```
grads_and_vars.append(self.optim.compute_gradients(self.grad_total_loss, var_list=[var])[0])
```

and

```
grads = tf.gradients(self.layer_out[k], var, self.grad_output[k])[0]
grads_and_vars.append((grads,var))
```

Are they doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the full code of that person, but basically:

- the first one applies a standard gradient to the variable, i.e. the gradient from the loss `self.grad_total_loss`
- the second one applies a specific gradient, here the gradient of `self.layer_out[k]` relative to `var`, and when we know that the gradients of `self.layer_out[k]`are `self.grad_output[k]`.

To put it another way, we backpropagate `self.grad_output[k]`from `self.layer_out[k]`to `var`.